# Integrate Amazon Payments on iOS (Swift or Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

We are making an app that can sell event tickets from an iOS app. Right now I have implemented Paypal and Stripe payments on my app to charge the customer.

I was asked to integrate Amazon payments on our "NATIVE iOS" app to charge the user of purchased event tickets. I found the integration instructions on the Amazon Payment site but it seems to be compatible for websites only. See https://payments.amazon.com/developer

This was written on their home page:
"Login and Pay with Amazon is the fast, easy and secure way to pay on desktop, tablet and mobile." - https://payments.amazon.com/home

Can you show me how to do it on Swift or Objective-C?

Note: This is about charging the client for payment of a product and not integrating the normal Amazon login or Amazon web services which I think is a different thing from "Amazon Payments" which should be similar to Stripe and Paypal.

Comment: @JulianE. There seems to be no Objective C or  Swift library for Amazon Payments. You can only pay on a web browser. So what we did was make a mobile website that will accept amazon payments. when the user tries to pay on the APP, a UIWebview showing our website will be pushed on the navigation stack. The UIWebview will check if the successPayment or failedPayment webpage is loaded and pop the UIWebview, showing a native iOS View again. (This method make everything look native because user doesn't need to leave the app)

Comment: Anyway there is a note on @David's answer below, not sure if what we did is a good or valid work around. We didn't make a Native version of the payment method, since it still on a UIWebview using their official web API's. Just similar to adding a button to redirect the user to our website and open safari.

Comment: Okay! Nice. Well if it works and looks good then all is good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: https://payments.amazon.com/documentation/lpwa/201749840#201749840

Note: The Amazon Payments service has been designed and developed for use within a web browser only. Our Service cannot be used within a native application (including, without limitation, iOS, Android, RIM and Windows operating systems). Amazon Payments reserves the right to suspend the Payment Account of any user of our services that has implemented our Service within a native application.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this resource I found some time back:
http://www.chupamobile.com/resources/amazon-mobile-payment

However, I am not one hundred percent sure you can actually integrate Amazon Payments into the iOS app natively, as there isn't an official SDK or API that you can use for Android or iOS. However what you could try to do is integrate their C# SDK into your project and then access it through your app.

Hope that helps.